# Bootstrap Multiselect: How to change backgroung color if None selected

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I have used Bootstrap Multiselect in my web form.I kept a validation checking on all input/select fields.if the form submits with any empty input or disabled options or None select then all the empty fields will change backgroung color to red.It seem all input and select works fine.However the select for multiselect i not changing the color.Here is the code part for the multiselect only:

```js
if($("#example-optionClass").val() == null){
    $("#example-optionClass").css('background-color','red');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example-optionClass').multiselect({
                    optionClass: function (element) {
                        var value = $(element).val();

                        if (value % 2 == 0) {
                            return 'even';
                        }
                        else {
                            return 'odd';
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #example-optionClass-container .multiselect-container li.odd {
                background: #eeeeee;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Bootstrap Multiselect Test</h2>
            <p>I want to change the Multiselect <b>background color</b>  If 'None Selected'</p>            
            <div id="example-optionClass-container">
                <select id="example-optionClass" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
                    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

What simple jquery i need to write for that? please help. thanks

Answer (score 4):

```js
function onchange_multi(){
  setTimeout(function(){ // use timeout because master script run and your script run
    var btn_def = $("#example-optionClass-container").find('.btn-default');
    if($("#example-optionClass").val() === null){
       btn_def.addClass('btn-danger')  //btn-danger default class of bootstrap
    }else{
       btn_def.removeClass('btn-danger')  
    }
  },50);
}


//onload
onchange_multi();

//onchange
$('#example-optionClass').on('change',function(){
  onchange_multi();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-optionClass').multiselect({
            
            optionClass: function(element) {
                var value = $(element).val();
 
                if (value%2 == 0) {
                    return 'even';
                }
                else {
                    return 'odd';
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #example-optionClass-container .multiselect-container li.odd {
        background: #eeeeee;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap Multiselect Test</h2>
  <p>I want to change the Multiselect <b>background color</b>  If 'None Selected'</p>            
  <div id="example-optionClass-container">
    <select id="example-optionClass" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```